# Install SSD and Windows to Mac Pro 2012

Tags: macos, bootcamp, startup, ssd, mac-pro

I have what I believe is a Mac Pro from 2012. It has 2 CPUs, 12 GB of RAM a 5770 and no disks. I want to stick an SSD in it and install Windows. The Mac Pro does not currently have any disks and hence OS.

So I stick a (Windows layout) keyboard in a USB port turn it on. I'm not quite sure how to navigate Mac on boot. I hit <kbd>alt</kbd> when I heard the chime, and it's meant to show me the boot devices. After I let go of <kbd>alt</kbd> , I see the mouse cursor appear, but I do not see my brand new SSD I installed... does it only pick up drives with certain formats?

If I don't have access to another Mac device what can I do to get it to boot to a DVD or something containing Windows? How do I get it to detect a boot device (even if there is no OS on it)?

Answer (score 2):

You have to install macOS first in order to run Bootcamp to install Windows.

Refer to [this support document](https://support.apple.com/HT204904) on how to boot into recovery mode and install macOS on your fresh drive.
In your case use **CMD+ALT+R** while booting to start the internet recovery.

Then you can follow [this document](https://support.apple.com/HT201468) on how to install Windows.

Comment: So I tried connecting the mac to my ethernet cable running directly into the router. When booting with CMR+ALT+R (even tried adding shift) it just ends up getting to a flashing folder. Also tried using the DVD drive and it just gets stuck showing apple icon. Any hints?